# UITableViewCell changes its label value every time I scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a reusableCell that has a label for which the values are supplied by an array. But the values of the label and the constraints change every time, my cellForRowAtIndexPath code looks like

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     if(indexPath.row % 2 == 0)
    {
        isReceived =TRUE;
    }
     else{
        isReceived = FALSE;
    }
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"id" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    ChatMessageCellTableViewCell *messageCell = (ChatMessageCellTableViewCell*) cell;
    if(messageCell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ChatMessageCellTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];

        messageCell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    else{
        [[messageCell formLabel]setText:messages[indexPath.row]];
        [messageCell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    } // this else part is just to make sure that the if has a else part as I saw many people it will work , but in my case it didn't help.

    [[self tableView] setEstimatedRowHeight:50.0];
    [self.tableView setRowHeight:UITableViewAutomaticDimension];

    return messageCell;
}
```

When I scroll the table, Values are changing. I tried many different way, but could not find a solution and I am so confused that I had to post my question.

Thank You

Comment: Did you register the nib to the UITableView?
e.g.
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ChatMessageCellTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"id"];

Comment: Yes I think this was my issue as I had not registered any nib with the UITableView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's bad practice to answer your own post, but I hope this helps someone

I was able to avoid those changes by changing the method cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *cellIdentifier = (indexPath.row % 2 == 0 ? @"EvenCell" : @"OddCell"); //using different identifier for every cell did the trick I guess
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    ChatMessageCellTableViewCell *messageCell = (ChatMessageCellTableViewCell*) cell; ;
    if (messageCell == nil) {
        messageCell = [[ChatMessageCellTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault
            reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        if(indexPath.row % 2 == 0)
        {
            isReceived =TRUE;
        }
        else{
            isReceived = FALSE;
        }
    }

        [[messageCell formLabel]setText:messages[indexPath.row]];
        [messageCell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    [[self tableView] setEstimatedRowHeight:50.0];
    [self.tableView setRowHeight:UITableViewAutomaticDimension];

    return messageCell;
}
```

I have commented the change's which I have made in order to prevent changes in the cell's while scrolling.

Thanks for all the support :)

Comment: Your initial question is incomplete - did not mention anything about multiple types of cells that you used hence why what people answer doesn't work for you. Pls be more detailed next time.

Comment: sorry for that, will make sure that next time.

Answer (score 0):

There is a wrong logic in your code, your code is only assign data for reused cell but not for new created cell. You should move the code in else bracket out like this.

```
ChatMessageCellTableViewCell *messageCell = (ChatMessageCellTableViewCell*) cell;
if(messageCell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ChatMessageCellTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];

    messageCell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
[[messageCell formLabel]setText:messages[indexPath.row]];
[messageCell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

Comment: whatever you suggested I have tried that but its of no use

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not familiar with Obj-C, but this may helpful to you.

```swift
if youHaveTitleText {
cell.title.text = data.displayText
} else {
cell.title.text = ""
}
```

Comment: you mean to set the label text only when the text is available and if not set to empty?

Comment: The text is taken from the array of strings , so obviously there the string will be available to be set @SureshMopidevi.